Measuring CM voltages for RS485 transceivers
For RS485 wiring I read that the common mode range is –7V to 12V. So I guess it means this has to be checked before starting any communication.
But in practice I'm wondering how this is done. And for the sake of making the question easy, I will use the following diagram where PLC master is connected to a slave using RS485 physical layer such as in a Modbus RTU. And I also assume in the bus the 120 Ohm terminations are done properly:

What procedure would reveal the CM voltage at the RS485 transceiver device inputs in practice to check whether this is in safe common mode range which is –7V to 12V?
What comes to my mind is:

First thing after the wiring, keep communication in idle state
Measure the voltage between As and Gs as Vas by a voltmeter
Measure the voltage between Bs and Gs as Vbs by a voltmeter
Calculate the CM voltage as (Vas + Vbs) / 2

Can I use the above procedure? (I also named the local grounds in different names and also mentioned earth ground in the diagram, where I assume earth ground is not directly connected to the transceiver ground Gs)

clarify, are you talking about during design, or during end-user operation?

The MOSBUS 485 interface might be an isolated type. You need to check on this because it makes a massive difference (a major improvement in CM stuff).

@Neil_UK During end user operation.

@Andyaka Good point. The slave input is RS485 to TTL converter. I have option to use an isolated one here: https://docs.m5stack.com/en/unit/iso485 (There's a schematic at the end of the page as well)

@user1245 the IC in that device is rated for a repetitive peak isolation voltage of 560 volts with a transient isolation up to 4 kV. However, that doesn't mean it can negotiate a noisy signal any more than a non-isolated IC so, you need to explain what is important to you.

You would generally design the system so that the end user would not have to worry about VCM. What happens if it's out of spec? What happens if it's a damaging level? These considerations should be taken care of at design time.

Normally you'd smack on a common mode choke and some TVS and that ought to be it. If the end user is worrying about common mode voltages, then that's a very unusual end user.

@Neil_UK I understand and have respect to both of your experiences, but I was wondering out of curiosity how to measure it(VCM) in practice especially for the case in question.

If the RS-485 related grounds of the devices are connected together, it should make it impossible that VCM is between 0V and 5V, and that each data line is also between 0V and 5V, unless something is damaged.

@Justme Thanks for the feedback. Are you saying the VCM is more an issue when the grounds are not connected? I also thought connecting grounds will solve VCM. But then what would an isolated chip prevent extra if grounds are already connected in the bus?

You measure VCM in the way you suggest, but, what with? If in design, you hook up a meter. In the field, you would have to use extra hardware, not many 485 tranceivers have voltage measurement built in. In the field, you will be controlling VCM anyway, or be subject to potentially damaging, communication stopping, your reputation destroying, excess levels of VCM. You control it by connecting the grounds, perhaps via antiparallel diodes which allow VCM of +/- 1 V or so to allow a little CM signal amplitude if needed, and slap on a common mode choke and TVS if required.

You're asking how to do something that's never required in the field. My questions above were Socratic to see if I could guide you to realising that yourself.

@user1245 Good questions. Maybe good to ask them separately or see if they are already asked and answered. RS-485 allows for +/- 7V difference between device grounds. Isolated RS-485 allows your interface to have 0V between your device and another device, even if your device electronics are at 1000VDC compared to RS-485 reference, which your computer will tie to 0V Earth.

Yes your Vcm measurement method seems correct. It is one half, of the sum, of the voltages between data wire and the interface ground.
So if e.g. both wires float at 2.5V in reference to that ground, Vcm is 2.5V.
If one wire is 5V and other wire is 0V, Vcm is also 2.5V.
Each data wire should itself be about within 0V and 6V range compared to ground, and the voltage difference between two data wires must not exceed 6V.
Generally, what the Vcm between ports means is how much there is voltage between the grounds of two device ports. And since you properly connected the ground wire between ports, there should be 0V between the ports and thus 0V common mode.
And since each port accepts +/- 7V difference between ground potentials, it translates to -7 and +12V on receiver input if receiver ground has +/- 7V compared to transmitter ground. But you can't have that scenario, unless your ground wire comes loose.

@Burglups RS-485 is good and robust interface, but it won't save you if you simply use it wrong to begin with. In the scenario you speak of, you would need shielded comms cable, with good separation to the power cable, and use a shielded power cable as well. And if there is something that causes so much Vcm, there is a ground loop with current in the RS-485 ground wire. Which is prevented by breaking the ground loop with isolated RS-485 interface, so there is no other currents running between transceivers. With proper design and planning, I bet no issues.
